# UITableView move up when keyboard is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have UITableView with UITextfields as the subview in contentView.

They work and all, but when I select the bottom ones, they are getting covered by the keyboard, so I want the UITableView to scroll up.

Here is my current code:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
NSValue *keyboardFrameValue = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
CGRect keyboardFrame = [[self view] convertRect:[keyboardFrameValue CGRectValue] fromView:nil];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [constraint setConstant:keyboardFrame.size.height];
    [self.myTableView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [constraint setConstant:0];
    [self.myTableView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
}
```

The problem with this is that it messes up the data, textfields are being added to the wrong Cells and stuff.

Hope that anyone can help out.

Comment: why don't you use third party library?

Comment: for what? the uitableview?

Comment: you can check this.....https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager or this.... https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, use an `UITableViewController`, the keyboard is handled automatically.

Otherwise, adjust the `contentInset` property of the table view as [outlined by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html).